# Glassfish 4: how to set application or module name for JNDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jndi, glassfish-4

I use EJB inside OSGi bundles. And now when I need to get EJB I have long jndi, for example:

```
bean = (InterfaceName) ctx.lookup("java:global/longBundleName_version/OrganizationDirBean!and.plus.path.and.InterfaceName");
```

I want to change this part:

```
longBundleName_version
```

I mean, when I deploy bundle this part must be set from [glassfish-]application.xml or from [glassfish-]-ejb-jar.xml or from any other xml descriptor. I want jndi name for my ejb to be like:

```
java:global/newBundleNameWithoutVersion/etc
```

The problem that I can't find what I must set in these files. All [variants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3431968/2022068) I found in internet  are not supported anymore and all I tried myself didn't work. Could you help me?

Please, don't offer mappedName as it can be used only(!) for remote beans. I do use beans which are at the same time both local and remote.

If someone is involved in glassfish development, could you at least point what bundles I must examine to find the question by myself? I will be very grateful.

Comment: Glassfish is open source, no? Why not read the relevant code to find out if or how it is possible?

Comment: @bmargulies Thank you for idea! I'll try, although I think it won't be so easy taking into consideration it consists a lot of code and I never worked with its code. And to tell the truth, I'm afraid I don't have experience enough.

Answer (score 3):

You should annotate your `EJB` like that:

```
@Remote(value = YourInterface.class)
@Stateless(mappedName = "java:global/fancy")
```

After that, `GF` logs says:

```
EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB YourInterfaceImpl: [java:global/fancy, java:global/fancy!com.example.YourInterface]]]
```

And at least I was able to inject like:

```
<!-- language:java -->

@EJB(lookup="java:global/fancy")
```

**So I think manual look up should also work.**

Comment: Thank you for your time. The problem is that what you offer is not portable JNDI name. And the second problem is that mappedName is used only for remote beans, but I have both local and remote.

Comment: Then probably it is not possible. If it would be possible, and you will deploy twice your application, which of the resources will be mapped to your custom JNDI?

Comment: That's possible. See the link I provided.