# Inject EJB bean from JSF managed bean programmatically

Tags: jsf, ejb, code-injection, managed-bean

I have EJB stateless bean.
How can I inject it to JSF managed bean by programmatic instead of @EJB annotation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't inject it programmatically. You can however obtain it programmatically. [EJBs are also available via JNDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-intro004.htm#GIRFL). Usually, you find those JNDI names/aliases printed in server startup log. At least JBoss / WildFly does that.

There are different JNDI name aliases:

```
java:global/APP_NAME[/MODULE_NAME]/EJB_NAME
```

```
java:app/MODULE_NAME/EJB_NAME
```

```
java:module/EJB_NAME
```

Where `/APP_NAME` is the name of the WAR or EAR application, and `/MODULE_NAME` is the name of the EJB module in case of an EAR application, or the WAR module in case of a single-WAR application (and this will be absent in `java:global` as it otherwise repeats `/APP_NAME`), and `/EJB_NAME` defaults to the class name of the EJB class.

The `java:global` is accessible through the entire server. The `java:app` is only accessible from inside the same application (WAR or EAR). The `java:module` is only accessible from inside the same module (EJB in case of EAR or WAR itself in case of single-WAR).

A JSF managed bean is obviously inside a WAR. If you've a single-WAR application, then `java:module/EJB_NAME` must work. If you've however an EAR project, then the EJB is obviously inside the EJB module, in that case the `java:module` won't work and you'd need `java:app` or `java:global`.

So, given an EJB like below,

```
@Stateless
public class FooService {}
```

it's in a single-WAR project named "foo_war" via JNDI available in a JSF managed bean as follows (usually you do that in `@PostConstruct` method):

```
InitialContext jndi = new InitialContext();

FooService fooService = (FooService) jndi.lookup("java:module/FooService");
// Or
FooService fooService = (FooService) jndi.lookup("java:app/foo_war/FooService");
// Or
FooService fooService = (FooService) jndi.lookup("java:global/foo_war/FooService");
```

or in an EAR project named "foo_ear" with an EJB module named "foo_ejb" with therein the EJB class (while the JSF managed bean is in the WAR module of the EAR project):

```
InitialContext jndi = new InitialContext();

FooService fooService = (FooService) jndi.lookup("java:app/foo_ejb/FooService");
// Or
FooService fooService = (FooService) jndi.lookup("java:global/foo_ear/foo_ejb/FooService");
```

Comment: To get the application and/or module name at runtime see [How can i config module and application name for JNDI Lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431357/how-can-i-config-module-and-application-name-for-jndi-lookups)